# Why doesn't golang have substring?

Tags: string, go, substring

Why doesn't go have a substring function?

Can i do something like prototyping from javascript so i can at least do something like:

```
string.substring(0,7)
```

or am i forced to use my function here?:

```
func substring(str string, start int, length int) string {
    return string([]rune(str)[start:length+start])
}
```

Comment: Why function? If you have byte offsets, str[from:to], if you have rune offsets, string([]rune(str)[from:to])

Comment: Work with byte offsets so that you can use string slice operations.  Programs that work with rune indexes convert to []rune, do some work on the runes and convert back to the string when done.

Comment: Because it doesn't need one.  `string.Substring(str, 0,7)` is a lot longer than `str[:7]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Substrings is a "thing" in Go too: slicing a `string` results in a `string` which shares memory with the original `string`.

The difference is that in Go the indices are byte-indices, not character or rune indices. Go stores the UTF-8 encoded byte sequence of texts in a `string`.

If your input consists of ASCII characters only (byte values less than 128), then using byte indices is the same as using rune indices:

```
s := "abcdef"
fmt.Println(s[1:3])
```

This will output:

```
bc
```

If your input may contain multi-byte unicode characters, then you have to decode the (UTF-8) bytes of the string. For that, there is the standard [`unicode/utf8`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/) package, or you may use `for range` over the `string` which does the same thing.

The `for range` over the string decodes the bytes, and each iteration "yields" one `rune` of the `string`, and also returns the starting byte position of the `rune`.

This is how we can use that to construct a `substr()` function:

```
func substr(s string, start, end int) string {
    counter, startIdx := 0, 0
    for i := range s {
        if counter == start {
            startIdx = i
        }
        if counter == end {
            return s[startIdx:i]
        }
        counter++
    }
    return s[startIdx:]
}
```

`substr()` takes a string and a `start` (inclusive) and `end` (exclusive) rune indices, and returns a substring according to that. Checks (like `start <= end`) are omitted for brevity.

Testing it:

```
s := "abcdef"
fmt.Println(substr(s, 1, 3))

s = "世界世界世界"
fmt.Println(substr(s, 1, 3))
fmt.Println(substr(s, 1, 100))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oqtxrzeDi9e)):

```
bc
界世
界世界世界
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be faster?:func substring(str string, start int, length int) string {
    return string([]rune(str)[start:length+start])
}

Comment: @KilianHertel Definitely not, because that copies the `string` content when converting to `rune` slice, and then slices it, and converts it back to `string` making another copy. My solution does not make any copies, the returned string is truly a substring of the input. Also, converting a `string` to `[]rune` has to decode all runes, while my solution only decodes what is necessary. Benchmark it if you want proof.

Comment: But s[1:3] would be the way to go then its 5 tines faster then substr. And substr is faster than substring pretty heavy impact though.

Comment: @KilianHertel As noted in the answer, simple slicing like `s[1:3]` is OK if the string only contains ASCII characters. But it does not work with the second example (`"世界世界世界"`), for that you need the presented `substr()` function. Note that `substr()` works with ASCII strings too.